# What type of R graph can I use to display frequency on the x axis and length on y?

Tags: r, graph

I have a dataset of length values for plants sampled in a number of specific square areas

eg., not actual data - just a representation

[image]

I want to create a graph in R that has the number of plants per plot (per area squared) on the x axis and the average length on the y axis - effectively exploring the effect of density per plot on length as pictured below.

[image]

Just wondering what the best function/package would be to do this in

Thanks

Comment: Read about barplot - https://r-graph-gallery.com/barplot.html

Comment: E.g. `library(ggplot2); ggplot(your_data, aes(Plot, Length)) + stat_summary(geom = 'col', fun = 'mean')`